# Heron's Method: prove convergence in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x>0,y>0$ and $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ where $f(0)=1$ and $f(n+1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(n)+\frac{4}{f(n)}\right)$. I want to show that f converges in $\mathbb{Q}$.

For this, I used that $f(n)>0\; \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, which implies $f(n)\geq 2$ for all $n\neq 0$ and further $f(n)^2\geq 4$ for all $n\neq 0$. Using this I showed that f is monotonically decreasing. So in $\mathbb{R}$ the limit exists (because the sequence is bounded). By using that $\lim_{n\mapsto \infty} f(n+1)=\lim_{n\mapsto \infty} f(n)$ i got an equation which I then solved for the limit.

Long story short: How can I prove that $f$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}$ (and what the limit was) without using anything that has to do with $\mathbb{R}$?

My idea for proving that $f$ converges is, to show that f is a cauchy-sequence (in $\mathbb{Q})$. Can anyone assist in finding a way to do so? I am stuck...

Thanks!

Comment: Prove that a decreasing sequence in ${\mathbb Q}$ bounded from below is Cauchy.

Comment: don't you need the supremum property to prove this in $\mathbb{R}$? So does it even work in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: No, take $\epsilon>0$. Only a finite number of pairs $(p, q)$ can have $|f(p) - f(q)|\ge \epsilon$ if $f$ is decreasing and bounded from below.

Comment: A Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb Q$ may well converge to a real number not in $\Bbb Q$. Take any sequence of rational numbers converging, say, to $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to show directly, that f converges (by using the definition) or if it is possible to show directly, that f is cauchy?